# How to JSON data instead of JSON path in Spark Structure Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I have data in a variable jsondata as below
`[{'sno': 1, 'number': '000-00-00000'}]`

How to use this data in `JSON()` during structure streaming in spark, which is actually expecting a path which i don't have.
I have tried below code, but threw an error: **TypeError: path can be only a single string**

`df=spark.readStream.json(jsondata)`

Please help on this.